# Celery with RabbitMQ creating too many queues

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-haystack

When running Django/Celery/RabbitMQ on production server, some tasks are sent and consumed correctly.  However, RabbitMQ starts using up all the CPU after processing is done.  I believe this is related to the following report.

[RabbitMQ on EC2 Consuming Tons of CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362829/rabbitmq-on-ec2-consuming-tons-of-cpu)

In that thread, it is suggested to set these config values:

- CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT
- CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES

I forked and customized the celery-haystack package to set both those values when calling appl_async(), however it seems to have had no effect.

I think Celery is creating a large number (one per task) of uid-named queues automatically to store results.  But I don't seem to be able to stop it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just got a day of digging into this problem myself. I think the two options you meantioned can be explained like this:

- `CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT`: if `True` then the results of tasks will be ignored, hence they won't return anything where you call them with `delay` or `apply_async`.
- `CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES`: the expiration time for a result stored in the result backend. You can set this option to a reasonable value so RabbitMQ can delete expired results.

The many queues generated are for storing results only. So in case you don't want to store any results, you can remove `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` option from your config file.

Have a ncie day!